# How to open several MappedByteBuffer in parallel in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

I need to write an algorithm which downloads parts of a file from different locations and merges them all in a single file on my local drive. The file may be huge (several giga bytes) but each part is small.

Each part has a header which says the file it's part of and also the offset byte where it's located in the file.
Every part is downloaded in its own thread.

Just after the header has been decoded, I open a MappedByteBuffer:

```
        MappedByteBuffer memoryMappedFile;
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file.toFile(), "rw")) {
            memoryMappedFile = raf.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, offset, mappedSize);
        }
```

The problem is that several threads could execute this code at the same time (while trying to map different parts of the same file) and it causes IOException (thrown by the above 'map' method) with message "This operation cannot be performed on a file having an open user mapped section" (this is a translation from a localized message).

If I synchronize the whole block, the exception is not thrown. So I guess it's ok to use several MappedByteBuffer on the same file as long as they're not open at the same time. Is it possible to achieve this result without synchronizing this part and if not, is there a better solution?
The program runs on Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you have to use `MappedByteBuffer`? You could get rid of those mapped buffers and use directly `RandomAccessFile` read and write methods. `RandomAccessFile` is not thread safe but as long as you ensure that your threads access different ranges you should not have troubles.

Comment: Why use multiples at all? There's no advantage. Just use a single `MappedByteBuffer` for the entire target file, and have the threads write into their own piece of it. In fact it's dubious whether there's any advantage to multi-threading this at all, unless you have a striped disk.

Comment: @mziccard, it's possible to do that but I think IO is faster with MappedByteBuffer

Comment: @EJP, this cannot work: MappedByteBuffer is not thread safe. Moreover, multi-threading really improves the IO as it doesn't write to disk but to ram and the OS handles the rest

Comment: @julian_CT2K2 You might consider using direct byte buffers (`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`) that are more suited for large files and when used with underlying system's I/O operations. Since `FileChannel` is thread-safe, if you split the file with no overlapping you should be able to soundly read/write in each thread to/from its direct byte buffer wtih good preformace.

Comment: It's threadsafe if your threads are accessiing different parts of the file. The disk isn't multithreaded so it is difficult to see how multiple threads are going to improve performance. Just hand-waving about magic occurring in the OS doesn't explain it.